# golang: HTTPS request yields "crypto/rsa: verification error"

Tags: https, go, rsa

I'm having trouble accessing `https` urls with the `net/http` package.

Here's a working example of the error:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  _, err := http.Get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/book/ltcbtc")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
}
```

This program yields the error,

```
Get https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/book/ltcbtc: crypto/rsa: verification error
```

The [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) for `net/http` clearly state,

> Get, Head, Post, and PostForm make HTTP (or HTTPS) requests

but I can't find any documentation on this error.

The [source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/rsa/rsa.go) for `crypto/rsa` only has this to say about the error:

```
// ErrVerification represents a failure to verify a signature.
// It is deliberately vague to avoid adaptive attacks.
var ErrVerification = errors.New("crypto/rsa: verification error")
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm pretty sure it's not their fault because Chrome is happy with their https certificate.

I've also tried using a `Client` with a `tls.Config` that has `InsecureSkipVerify` set to `true`, but that didn't seem to shut this error up.

Comment: Many unix distributions don't have the most up to date list of signing keys for PKI chains. In particular Thawte certs need an additonal chain of certs to validate their certs. Browsers generally are much more up to date.

Comment: Here's more on the thawte issue. https://community.thawte.com/forums/downloading-intermediate-ca-bundle-ssl123

Comment: @ArturSapek: Chrome probably uses its own set of certificates, independent of the OS. Have you tried using `openssl s_client -connect api.bitfinex.com:443`?

Comment: I tried the above using ubuntu 12.04 and go 1.2 and it worked fine.  Suggest you post OS details and output of `go version`.

Comment: Upgrading go fixed it! I really need to learn to just always try that before asking anyone for help.

For documentation purposes, the go version I was running was `go version devel +f4d1cb8d9a91 Thu Sep 19 22:34:33 2013 +1000 darwin/amd64`. Upgrading to the newest, `go version go1.2.1 darwin/amd64`, fixed this issue.

Thanks for slapping me in the head, I needed that. What an obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go uses the system root SSL certificate under [linux](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/x509/root_unix.go) and [windows](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/x509/root_windows.go).

Given that the test works fine on my ubuntu 12.04 box with go 1.2, either

1. You are using a very old version of go
2. Your system has out of date root certificates

If you want to update your root certificates, [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125) is a hint for windows. Googling should find you more ideas for other OSes.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I've tried updating OS X, my root certificates, and even `openssl` just in case that mattered. I'm still getting the error. However it seems like I'm able to load other domains this way, and I'm even able to load this problematic domain on my Linode box (running CentOS). But for some reason my Mac just doesn't like Bitfinex's SSL cert. Still clueless how to even debug this for now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened because I set the wrong public key for verifying the token. When I changed it to the correct one, it worked like a charm.